# Django MySql Row Locking

Tags: django, orm

I'm looking to use a Model, backed by a mysql table, as a job queue, shared among concurrent processes. I'm trying to avoid a situation where 2 processes execute the same job. The first thought would be to add a dirty flag to a row (job), that's marked when a process is executing that job. But then we have the classic problem where checking the dirty bit is a distinct operation from writing the dirty bit. How could I make the 2 operations atomic?

Ideally, each row would have a spinlock, which can be locked by a process updating the row, and prevents other processes for accessing the row. Does Django support this concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`QuerySet.select_for_update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) is in the development version. On stable releases you'll need to use raw queries yourself.